# Option Data from google finance in Json format not parse-able in Groovy

Tags: json, groovy

I am trying to parse Option data from google finance using JsonSlurper in Groovy. I get an error and looking at the data, it seems it is not proper Json format. (It is missing quotes around values).
Is this normal. Do I have to massage this data before JsonSlurper will parse it. I can see the data after puts would be in proper format.

Here is the [url](https://www.google.com/finance/option_chain?q=GOOG&output=json) that I get the data from :

This is the error that I get in groovy:

```
Encountered exception : Lexing failed on line: 1, column: 2, while reading 'e', no possible valid JSON value or punctuation could be recognized. -
```

This is the the data that is returned from the url:

```
{expiry:{y:2013,m:5,d:31},expirations:[{y:2013,m:5,d:31},{y:2013,m:6,d:7},{y:2013,m:6,d:14},{y:2013,m:6,d:22},{y:2013,m:6,d:28},{y:2013,m:7,d:20},{y:2013,m:8,d:17},{y:2013,m:9,d:21},{y:2013,m:12,d:21},{y:2014,m:1,d:18},{y:2015,m:1,d:17}],puts:[{cid:"861808824253659",name:"",s:"GOOG130531P00625000",e:"OPRA",p:"0.05",cs:"chb",c:"0.00",cp:"0.00",b:"-",a:"0.05",oi:"14",vol:"-",strike:"625.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"90291598673294",name:"",s:"GOOG130531P00630000",e:"OPRA",p:"0.50",cs:"chb",c:"0.00",cp:"0.00",b:"-",a:"0.05",oi:"3",vol:"-",strike:"630.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"883084064658290",name:"",s:"GOOG130531P00635000",e:"OPRA",p:"0.50",cs:"chb",c:"0.00",cp:"0.00",b:"-",a:"0.05",oi:"3",vol:"-",strike:"635.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"550606621196196",name:"",s:"GOOG130531P00640000",e:"OPRA",p:"0.50",cs:"chb",c:"0.00",cp:"0.00",b:"-",a:"0.05",oi:"6",vol:"-",strike:"640.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"907661465271381",name:"",s:"GOOG130531P00645000",e:"OPRA",p:"0.76",cs:"chb",c:"0.00",cp:"0.00",b:"-",a:"0.05",oi:"4",vol:"-",strike:"645.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"312331955116595",name:"",s:"GOOG130531P00650000",e:"OPRA",p:"0.50",cs:"chb",c:"0.00",cp:"0.00",b:"-",a:"0.05",oi:"7",vol:"-",strike:"650.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"1034371554903574",name:"",s:"GOOG130531P00655000",e:"OPRA",p:"0.05",cs:"chb",c:"0.00",cp:"0.00",b:"-",a:"0.05",oi:"138",vol:"-",strike:"655.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"849038193044261",name:"",s:"GOOG130531P00660000",e:"OPRA",p:"0.05",cs:"chb",c:"0.00",cp:"0.00",b:"-",a:"0.05",oi:"221",vol:"-",strike:"660.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"448843840017009",name:"",s:"GOOG130531P00665000",e:"OPRA",p:"0.05",cs:"chb",c:"0.00",cp:"0.00",b:"-",a:"0.05",oi:"17",vol:"-",strike:"665.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"956560337544029",name:"",s:"GOOG130531P00670000",e:"OPRA",p:"0.05",cs:"chb",c:"0.00",cp:"0.00",b:"-",a:"0.05",oi:"89",vol:"-",strike:"670.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"168619215452014",name:"",s:"GOOG130531P00675000",e:"OPRA",p:"0.20",cs:"chb",c:"0.00",cp:"0.00",b:"-",a:"0.05",oi:"4",vol:"-",strike:"675.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"1117974573979659",name:"",s:"GOOG130531P00680000",e:"OPRA",p:"0.15",cs:"chb",c:"0.00",cp:"0.00",b:"-",a:"0.05",oi:"8",vol:"-",strike:"680.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"753362057423145",name:"",s:"GOOG130531P00685000",e:"OPRA",p:"0.05",cs:"chb",c:"0.00",cp:"0.00",b:"-",a:"0.05",oi:"64",vol:"-",strike:"685.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"764049961140541",name:"",s:"GOOG130531P00690000",e:"OPRA",p:"0.35",cs:"chb",c:"0.00",cp:"0.00",b:"-",a:"0.05",oi:"19",vol:"-",strike:"690.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"856579959673404",name:"",s:"GOOG130531P00695000",e:"OPRA",p:"0.15",cs:"chb",c:"0.00",cp:"0.00",b:"-",a:"0.05",oi:"52",vol:"-",strike:"695.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"824170367827899",name:"",s:"GOOG130531P00700000",e:"OPRA",p:"0.25",cs:"chb",c:"0.00",cp:"0.00",b:"-",a:"0.70",oi:"10",vol:"-",strike:"700.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"414605646886183",name:"",s:"GOOG130531P00705000",e:"OPRA",p:"0.05",cs:"chb",c:"0.00",cp:"0.00",b:"-",a:"0.05",oi:"211",vol:"-",strike:"705.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"1123808986964380",name:"",s:"GOOG130531P00710000",e:"OPRA",p:"0.35",cs:"chb",c:"0.00",cp:"0.00",b:"-",a:"0.65",oi:"28",vol:"-",strike:"710.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"428007176517959",name:"",s:"GOOG130531P00715000",e:"OPRA",p:"0.05",cs:"chb",c:"0.00",cp:"0.00",b:"-",a:"0.05",oi:"96",vol:"-",strike:"715.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"1004640940579345",name:"",s:"GOOG130531P00720000",e:"OPRA",p:"1.15",cs:"chb",c:"0.00",cp:"0.00",b:"0.05",a:"0.55",oi:"1",vol:"-",strike:"720.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"547870112882747",name:"",s:"GOOG130531P00725000",e:"OPRA",p:"0.05",cs:"chb",c:"0.00",cp:"0.00",b:"-",a:"0.05",oi:"26",vol:"-",strike:"725.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"713283828090500",name:"",s:"GOOG130531P00730000",e:"OPRA",p:"0.75",cs:"chb",c:"0.00",cp:"0.00",b:"-",a:"0.65",oi:"16",vol:"-",strike:"730.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"330110346878283",name:"",s:"GOOG130531P00735000",e:"OPRA",p:"0.50",cs:"chb",c:"0.00",cp:"0.00",b:"-",a:"0.05",oi:"6",vol:"-",strike:"735.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"741172786814707",name:"",s:"GOOG130531P00740000",e:"OPRA",p:"0.60",cs:"chb",c:"0.00",cp:"0.00",b:"-",a:"0.40",oi:"11",vol:"-",strike:"740.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"305806735527325",name:"",s:"GOOG130531P00745000",e:"OPRA",p:"0.10",cs:"chb",c:"0.00",cp:"0.00",b:"-",a:"0.05",oi:"16",vol:"-",strike:"745.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"836255382420185",name:"",s:"GOOG130531P00750000",e:"OPRA",p:"0.95",cs:"chb",c:"0.00",cp:"0.00",b:"-",a:"0.40",oi:"28",vol:"-",strike:"750.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"10060751156355",name:"",s:"GOOG130531P00755000",e:"OPRA",p:"0.05",cs:"chb",c:"0.00",cp:"0.00",b:"-",a:"0.10",oi:"55",vol:"-",strike:"755.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"184650813944442",name:"",s:"GOOG130531P00760000",e:"OPRA",p:"0.25",cs:"chb",c:"0.00",cp:"0.00",b:"-",a:"0.40",oi:"14",vol:"-",strike:"760.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"439480549217736",name:"",s:"GOOG130531P00765000",e:"OPRA",p:"0.10",cs:"chb",c:"0.00",cp:"0.00",b:"-",a:"0.10",oi:"97",vol:"-",strike:"765.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"308783986011504",name:"",s:"GOOG130531P00770000",e:"OPRA",p:"0.20",cs:"chb",c:"0.00",cp:"0.00",b:"-",a:"0.65",oi:"20",vol:"-",strike:"770.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"51018175031907",name:"",s:"GOOG130531P00775000",e:"OPRA",p:"0.15",cs:"chb",c:"0.00",cp:"0.00",b:"-",a:"0.10",oi:"145",vol:"-",strike:"775.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"917630774138659",name:"",s:"GOOG130531P00780000",e:"OPRA",p:"0.80",cs:"chb",c:"0.00",cp:"0.00",b:"-",a:"0.40",oi:"11",vol:"-",strike:"780.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"1116428272838913",name:"",s:"GOOG130531P00785000",e:"OPRA",p:"0.05",cs:"chr",c:"-0.10",cp:"-66.67",b:"-",a:"0.10",oi:"71",vol:"3",strike:"785.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"768225161293425",name:"",s:"GOOG130531P00790000",e:"OPRA",p:"0.25",cs:"chb",c:"0.00",cp:"0.00",b:"-",a:"0.60",oi:"16",vol:"-",strike:"790.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"755499966485666",name:"",s:"GOOG130531P00795000",e:"OPRA",p:"0.21",cs:"chb",c:"0.00",cp:"0.00",b:"-",a:"0.05",oi:"107",vol:"-",strike:"795.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"1013649638331262",name:"",s:"GOOG130531P00800000",e:"OPRA",p:"0.20",cs:"chb",c:"0.00",cp:"0.00",b:"-",a:"0.40",oi:"56",vol:"-",strike:"800.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"357377673137695",name:"",s:"GOOG130531P00805000",e:"OPRA",p:"0.05",cs:"chr",c:"-0.23",cp:"-82.14",b:"0.05",a:"0.10",oi:"3615",vol:"123",strike:"805.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"690708626756771",name:"",s:"GOOG130531P00810000",e:"OPRA",p:"0.75",cs:"chb",c:"0.00",cp:"0.00",b:"-",a:"0.25",oi:"28",vol:"-",strike:"810.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"21150003535275",name:"",s:"GOOG130531P00815000",e:"OPRA",p:"0.05",cs:"chr",c:"-0.20",cp:"-80.00",b:"0.05",a:"0.15",oi:"177",vol:"6",strike:"815.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"275905429065075",name:"",s:"GOOG130531P00820000",e:"OPRA",p:"0.08",cs:"chr",c:"-0.24",cp:"-75.00",b:"0.05",a:"0.15",oi:"1037",vol:"107",strike:"820.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"1055025518544642",name:"",s:"GOOG130531P00825000",e:"OPRA",p:"0.70",cs:"chb",c:"0.00",cp:"0.00",b:"-",a:"0.40",oi:"3",vol:"-",strike:"825.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"1035321415642280",name:"",s:"GOOG130531P00830000",e:"OPRA",p:"0.13",cs:"chr",c:"-0.40",cp:"-75.47",b:"0.10",a:"0.20",oi:"489",vol:"68",strike:"830.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"70557296969979",name:"",s:"GOOG130531P00835000",e:"OPRA",p:"0.63",cs:"chb",c:"0.00",cp:"0.00",b:"0.10",a:"0.40",oi:"43",vol:"-",strike:"835.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"29904266868370",name:"",s:"GOOG130531P00840000",e:"OPRA",p:"1.40",cs:"chb",c:"0.00",cp:"0.00",b:"0.05",a:"0.30",oi:"34",vol:"-",strike:"840.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"60994034524162",name:"",s:"GOOG130531P00845000",e:"OPRA",p:"0.25",cs:"chr",c:"-0.95",cp:"-79.17",b:"0.25",a:"0.30",oi:"620",vol:"138",strike:"845.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"1062537796162167",name:"",s:"GOOG130531P00850000",e:"OPRA",p:"1.80",cs:"chb",c:"0.00",cp:"0.00",b:"0.20",a:"0.65",oi:"116",vol:"-",strike:"850.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"985844474705712",name:"",s:"GOOG130531P00855000",e:"OPRA",p:"0.51",cs:"chr",c:"-1.78",cp:"-77.73",b:"0.50",a:"0.55",oi:"578",vol:"377",strike:"855.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"412696606024360",name:"",s:"GOOG130531P00860000",e:"OPRA",p:"3.50",cs:"chb",c:"0.00",cp:"0.00",b:"0.55",a:"0.90",oi:"150",vol:"-",strike:"860.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"788760175384132",name:"",s:"GOOG130531P00865000",e:"OPRA",p:"5.50",cs:"chb",c:"0.00",cp:"0.00",b:"0.85",a:"1.30",oi:"169",vol:"-",strike:"865.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"495262825571032",name:"",s:"GOOG130531P00870000",e:"OPRA",p:"1.60",cs:"chr",c:"-4.80",cp:"-75.00",b:"1.65",a:"1.75",oi:"1993",vol:"1044",strike:"870.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"784479429576717",name:"",s:"GOOG130531P00875000",e:"OPRA",p:"3.00",cs:"chr",c:"-6.28",cp:"-67.67",b:"2.40",a:"2.65",oi:"172",vol:"127",strike:"875.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"475018278612528",name:"",s:"GOOG130531P00880000",e:"OPRA",p:"3.30",cs:"chr",c:"-9.60",cp:"-74.42",b:"3.60",a:"4.00",oi:"304",vol:"92",strike:"880.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"23479753271876",name:"",s:"GOOG130531P00885000",e:"OPRA",p:"5.60",cs:"chr",c:"-9.50",cp:"-62.91",b:"5.40",a:"5.70",oi:"911",vol:"1053",strike:"885.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"752454851539195",name:"",s:"GOOG130531P00890000",e:"OPRA",p:"7.90",cs:"chr",c:"-10.49",cp:"-57.04",b:"7.60",a:"8.00",oi:"531",vol:"918",strike:"890.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"70240546867537",name:"",s:"GOOG130531P00895000",e:"OPRA",p:"10.40",cs:"chr",c:"-12.33",cp:"-54.25",b:"10.10",a:"10.80",oi:"252",vol:"231",strike:"895.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"897963621776473",name:"",s:"GOOG130531P00900000",e:"OPRA",p:"13.49",cs:"chr",c:"-14.14",cp:"-51.18",b:"12.00",a:"14.50",oi:"131",vol:"4",strike:"900.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"85067464862382",name:"",s:"GOOG130531P00905000",e:"OPRA",p:"23.60",cs:"chb",c:"0.00",cp:"0.00",b:"15.80",a:"18.60",oi:"0",vol:"20",strike:"905.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"805187710443767",name:"",s:"GOOG130531P00910000",e:"OPRA",p:"20.20",cs:"chr",c:"-18.50",cp:"-47.80",b:"21.50",a:"22.50",oi:"576",vol:"37",strike:"910.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"885641012669822",name:"",s:"GOOG130531P00915000",e:"OPRA",p:"-",c:"-",b:"24.60",a:"27.30",oi:"0",vol:"-",strike:"915.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"899858163597569",name:"",s:"GOOG130531P00920000",e:"OPRA",p:"31.00",cs:"chr",c:"-17.00",cp:"-35.42",b:"30.10",a:"32.00",oi:"127",vol:"9",strike:"920.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"384946575665642",name:"",s:"GOOG130531P00925000",e:"OPRA",p:"-",c:"-",b:"34.10",a:"36.90",oi:"0",vol:"-",strike:"925.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"195709831580001",name:"",s:"GOOG130531P00930000",e:"OPRA",p:"-",c:"-",b:"39.10",a:"41.80",oi:"0",vol:"-",strike:"930.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"105979139287680",name:"",s:"GOOG130531P00935000",e:"OPRA",p:"-",c:"-",b:"44.10",a:"46.70",oi:"0",vol:"-",strike:"935.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"178992314903890",name:"",s:"GOOG130531P00940000",e:"OPRA",p:"-",c:"-",b:"49.00",a:"51.70",oi:"0",vol:"-",strike:"940.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"1081213298325092",name:"",s:"GOOG130531P00945000",e:"OPRA",p:"-",c:"-",b:"54.00",a:"57.00",oi:"0",vol:"-",strike:"945.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"849137800680828",name:"",s:"GOOG130531P00950000",e:"OPRA",p:"-",c:"-",b:"59.40",a:"61.60",oi:"0",vol:"-",strike:"950.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"252708185356048",name:"",s:"GOOG130531P00955000",e:"OPRA",p:"-",c:"-",b:"63.90",a:"67.60",oi:"0",vol:"-",strike:"955.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"849787286766910",name:"",s:"GOOG130531P00960000",e:"OPRA",p:"-",c:"-",b:"68.90",a:"71.60",oi:"0",vol:"-",strike:"960.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"39686410476830",name:"",s:"GOOG130531P00965000",e:"OPRA",p:"-",c:"-",b:"74.00",a:"77.20",oi:"0",vol:"-",strike:"965.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"}],calls:[{cid:"897932155474025",name:"",s:"GOOG130531C00625000",e:"OPRA",p:"-",c:"-",b:"262.70",a:"265.60",oi:"0",vol:"-",strike:"625.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"184287418485356",name:"",s:"GOOG130531C00630000",e:"OPRA",p:"248.20",cs:"chb",c:"0.00",cp:"0.00",b:"257.70",a:"260.60",oi:"5",vol:"-",strike:"630.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"905931936433954",name:"",s:"GOOG130531C00635000",e:"OPRA",p:"-",c:"-",b:"252.70",a:"255.60",oi:"0",vol:"-",strike:"635.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"135801183483562",name:"",s:"GOOG130531C00640000",e:"OPRA",p:"-",c:"-",b:"247.70",a:"250.60",oi:"0",vol:"-",strike:"640.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"543749135131573",name:"",s:"GOOG130531C00645000",e:"OPRA",p:"-",c:"-",b:"242.70",a:"245.60",oi:"0",vol:"-",strike:"645.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"430718357015828",name:"",s:"GOOG130531C00650000",e:"OPRA",p:"208.30",cs:"chb",c:"0.00",cp:"0.00",b:"237.70",a:"240.60",oi:"2",vol:"-",strike:"650.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"188702697546621",name:"",s:"GOOG130531C00655000",e:"OPRA",p:"-",c:"-",b:"232.70",a:"235.60",oi:"0",vol:"-",strike:"655.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"828515608830763",name:"",s:"GOOG130531C00660000",e:"OPRA",p:"-",c:"-",b:"227.70",a:"230.60",oi:"0",vol:"-",strike:"660.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"999908579656355",name:"",s:"GOOG130531C00665000",e:"OPRA",p:"215.00",cs:"chb",c:"0.00",cp:"0.00",b:"222.70",a:"225.60",oi:"6",vol:"-",strike:"665.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"543778324287872",name:"",s:"GOOG130531C00670000",e:"OPRA",p:"-",c:"-",b:"218.30",a:"220.60",oi:"0",vol:"-",strike:"670.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"911061111100062",name:"",s:"GOOG130531C00675000",e:"OPRA",p:"-",c:"-",b:"213.30",a:"215.60",oi:"0",vol:"-",strike:"675.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"530480483916026",name:"",s:"GOOG130531C00680000",e:"OPRA",p:"-",c:"-",b:"208.20",a:"210.60",oi:"0",vol:"-",strike:"680.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"972896973547783",name:"",s:"GOOG130531C00685000",e:"OPRA",p:"-",c:"-",b:"202.70",a:"205.70",oi:"0",vol:"-",strike:"685.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"703518576890345",name:"",s:"GOOG130531C00690000",e:"OPRA",p:"-",c:"-",b:"198.30",a:"200.60",oi:"0",vol:"-",strike:"690.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"173645130459646",name:"",s:"GOOG130531C00695000",e:"OPRA",p:"-",c:"-",b:"193.30",a:"195.60",oi:"0",vol:"-",strike:"695.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"252936815518459",name:"",s:"GOOG130531C00700000",e:"OPRA",p:"-",c:"-",b:"187.30",a:"191.50",oi:"0",vol:"-",strike:"700.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"40857533404165",name:"",s:"GOOG130531C00705000",e:"OPRA",p:"-",c:"-",b:"183.30",a:"185.60",oi:"0",vol:"-",strike:"705.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"957476173492076",name:"",s:"GOOG130531C00710000",e:"OPRA",p:"-",c:"-",b:"177.30",a:"181.50",oi:"0",vol:"-",strike:"710.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"108863832559161",name:"",s:"GOOG130531C00715000",e:"OPRA",p:"-",c:"-",b:"173.20",a:"175.60",oi:"0",vol:"-",strike:"715.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"98617325850106",name:"",s:"GOOG130531C00720000",e:"OPRA",p:"-",c:"-",b:"168.20",a:"170.60",oi:"0",vol:"-",strike:"720.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"753686669907511",name:"",s:"GOOG130531C00725000",e:"OPRA",p:"-",c:"-",b:"163.30",a:"165.60",oi:"0",vol:"-",strike:"725.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"489933059142682",name:"",s:"GOOG130531C00730000",e:"OPRA",p:"-",c:"-",b:"157.30",a:"161.50",oi:"0",vol:"-",strike:"730.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"905425017312349",name:"",s:"GOOG130531C00735000",e:"OPRA",p:"174.80",cs:"chb",c:"0.00",cp:"0.00",b:"152.70",a:"155.70",oi:"1",vol:"-",strike:"735.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"136536386201059",name:"",s:"GOOG130531C00740000",e:"OPRA",p:"-",c:"-",b:"147.30",a:"151.50",oi:"0",vol:"-",strike:"740.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"147619908144017",name:"",s:"GOOG130531C00745000",e:"OPRA",p:"-",c:"-",b:"142.70",a:"145.70",oi:"0",vol:"-",strike:"745.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"966255278051458",name:"",s:"GOOG130531C00750000",e:"OPRA",p:"-",c:"-",b:"137.30",a:"141.50",oi:"0",vol:"-",strike:"750.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"91531149317385",name:"",s:"GOOG130531C00755000",e:"OPRA",p:"-",c:"-",b:"132.70",a:"135.70",oi:"0",vol:"-",strike:"755.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"1073058963314671",name:"",s:"GOOG130531C00760000",e:"OPRA",p:"-",c:"-",b:"127.70",a:"130.70",oi:"0",vol:"-",strike:"760.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"211715618356204",name:"",s:"GOOG130531C00765000",e:"OPRA",p:"-",c:"-",b:"122.90",a:"125.70",oi:"0",vol:"-",strike:"765.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"864401376962645",name:"",s:"GOOG130531C00770000",e:"OPRA",p:"-",c:"-",b:"117.30",a:"121.60",oi:"0",vol:"-",strike:"770.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"625513742158849",name:"",s:"GOOG130531C00775000",e:"OPRA",p:"-",c:"-",b:"113.30",a:"115.70",oi:"0",vol:"-",strike:"775.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"150940569707753",name:"",s:"GOOG130531C00780000",e:"OPRA",p:"97.87",cs:"chb",c:"0.00",cp:"0.00",b:"108.30",a:"110.80",oi:"1",vol:"-",strike:"780.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"1096966496977199",name:"",s:"GOOG130531C00785000",e:"OPRA",p:"-",c:"-",b:"102.70",a:"105.90",oi:"0",vol:"-",strike:"785.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"596267655966317",name:"",s:"GOOG130531C00790000",e:"OPRA",p:"68.00",cs:"chb",c:"0.00",cp:"0.00",b:"97.30",a:"101.60",oi:"11",vol:"-",strike:"790.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"797644140819446",name:"",s:"GOOG130531C00795000",e:"OPRA",p:"-",c:"-",b:"92.70",a:"95.90",oi:"0",vol:"-",strike:"795.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"67114730428643",name:"",s:"GOOG130531C00800000",e:"OPRA",p:"90.20",cs:"chb",c:"0.00",cp:"0.00",b:"87.40",a:"91.10",oi:"48",vol:"-",strike:"800.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"524083644435811",name:"",s:"GOOG130531C00805000",e:"OPRA",p:"76.20",cs:"chb",c:"0.00",cp:"0.00",b:"82.90",a:"85.80",oi:"10",vol:"-",strike:"805.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"1027523638915015",name:"",s:"GOOG130531C00810000",e:"OPRA",p:"25.30",cs:"chb",c:"0.00",cp:"0.00",b:"78.50",a:"81.30",oi:"28",vol:"-",strike:"810.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"731421388062365",name:"",s:"GOOG130531C00815000",e:"OPRA",p:"94.02",cs:"chb",c:"0.00",cp:"0.00",b:"73.10",a:"75.70",oi:"3",vol:"-",strike:"815.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"201733430660498",name:"",s:"GOOG130531C00820000",e:"OPRA",p:"53.87",cs:"chb",c:"0.00",cp:"0.00",b:"68.60",a:"71.20",oi:"13",vol:"-",strike:"820.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"424269582116081",name:"",s:"GOOG130531C00825000",e:"OPRA",p:"-",c:"-",b:"63.60",a:"66.30",oi:"0",vol:"-",strike:"825.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"1108741066703867",name:"",s:"GOOG130531C00830000",e:"OPRA",p:"55.50",cs:"chb",c:"0.00",cp:"0.00",b:"58.40",a:"60.70",oi:"71",vol:"-",strike:"830.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"665032675403725",name:"",s:"GOOG130531C00835000",e:"OPRA",p:"65.70",cs:"chb",c:"0.00",cp:"0.00",b:"53.50",a:"55.70",oi:"14",vol:"-",strike:"835.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"870334633948548",name:"",s:"GOOG130531C00840000",e:"OPRA",p:"50.00",cs:"chb",c:"0.00",cp:"0.00",b:"48.70",a:"51.30",oi:"35",vol:"-",strike:"840.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"607302185263535",name:"",s:"GOOG130531C00845000",e:"OPRA",p:"-",c:"-",b:"43.80",a:"46.40",oi:"0",vol:"-",strike:"845.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"260537929897126",name:"",s:"GOOG130531C00850000",e:"OPRA",p:"24.20",cs:"chb",c:"0.00",cp:"0.00",b:"38.80",a:"41.50",oi:"60",vol:"-",strike:"850.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"869025962460528",name:"",s:"GOOG130531C00855000",e:"OPRA",p:"-",c:"-",b:"33.90",a:"36.70",oi:"0",vol:"-",strike:"855.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"271885603677647",name:"",s:"GOOG130531C00860000",e:"OPRA",p:"31.20",cs:"chb",c:"0.00",cp:"0.00",b:"29.20",a:"31.40",oi:"49",vol:"-",strike:"860.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"328801446656020",name:"",s:"GOOG130531C00865000",e:"OPRA",p:"26.95",cs:"chg",c:"+14.95",cp:"124.58",b:"24.80",a:"25.80",oi:"178",vol:"34",strike:"865.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"829450250741566",name:"",s:"GOOG130531C00870000",e:"OPRA",p:"19.10",cs:"chg",c:"+9.90",cp:"107.61",b:"20.20",a:"22.10",oi:"138",vol:"13",strike:"870.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"989626103025718",name:"",s:"GOOG130531C00875000",e:"OPRA",p:"12.50",cs:"chg",c:"+5.71",cp:"84.09",b:"16.10",a:"17.90",oi:"61",vol:"10",strike:"875.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"1105249690063656",name:"",s:"GOOG130531C00880000",e:"OPRA",p:"13.00",cs:"chg",c:"+8.20",cp:"170.83",b:"12.40",a:"14.90",oi:"252",vol:"35",strike:"880.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"339698646824918",name:"",s:"GOOG130531C00885000",e:"OPRA",p:"9.70",cs:"chg",c:"+6.40",cp:"193.94",b:"9.60",a:"9.90",oi:"1126",vol:"1868",strike:"885.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"280517630346946",name:"",s:"GOOG130531C00890000",e:"OPRA",p:"6.94",cs:"chg",c:"+5.09",cp:"275.14",b:"6.70",a:"7.20",oi:"262",vol:"432",strike:"890.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"963465706946796",name:"",s:"GOOG130531C00895000",e:"OPRA",p:"4.75",cs:"chg",c:"+3.41",cp:"254.48",b:"4.60",a:"4.90",oi:"467",vol:"1408",strike:"895.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"183457594845045",name:"",s:"GOOG130531C00900000",e:"OPRA",p:"3.13",cs:"chg",c:"+2.18",cp:"229.47",b:"3.10",a:"3.20",oi:"1627",vol:"2036",strike:"900.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"646238429691215",name:"",s:"GOOG130531C00905000",e:"OPRA",p:"2.00",cs:"chg",c:"+1.36",cp:"212.50",b:"1.95",a:"2.05",oi:"793",vol:"951",strike:"905.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"212732374141821",name:"",s:"GOOG130531C00910000",e:"OPRA",p:"0.65",cs:"chb",c:"0.00",cp:"0.00",b:"1.15",a:"1.45",oi:"78",vol:"-",strike:"910.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"710257727382042",name:"",s:"GOOG130531C00915000",e:"OPRA",p:"0.95",cs:"chg",c:"+0.63",cp:"196.88",b:"0.65",a:"0.90",oi:"40",vol:"7",strike:"915.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"563703158549966",name:"",s:"GOOG130531C00920000",e:"OPRA",p:"0.22",cs:"chb",c:"0.00",cp:"0.00",b:"0.20",a:"0.80",oi:"70",vol:"-",strike:"920.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"834257765385117",name:"",s:"GOOG130531C00925000",e:"OPRA",p:"0.37",cs:"chg",c:"+0.22",cp:"146.67",b:"0.35",a:"0.40",oi:"280",vol:"262",strike:"925.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"420529541878506",name:"",s:"GOOG130531C00930000",e:"OPRA",p:"0.95",cs:"chb",c:"0.00",cp:"0.00",b:"0.10",a:"0.40",oi:"8",vol:"-",strike:"930.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"888055439268652",name:"",s:"GOOG130531C00935000",e:"OPRA",p:"0.75",cs:"chb",c:"0.00",cp:"0.00",b:"-",a:"0.40",oi:"14",vol:"-",strike:"935.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"801449057323065",name:"",s:"GOOG130531C00940000",e:"OPRA",p:"0.45",cs:"chb",c:"0.00",cp:"0.00",b:"-",a:"0.40",oi:"88",vol:"-",strike:"940.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"607038769941357",name:"",s:"GOOG130531C00945000",e:"OPRA",p:"0.55",cs:"chb",c:"0.00",cp:"0.00",b:"-",a:"0.40",oi:"14",vol:"-",strike:"945.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"667068548867948",name:"",s:"GOOG130531C00950000",e:"OPRA",p:"0.45",cs:"chb",c:"0.00",cp:"0.00",b:"-",a:"0.40",oi:"60",vol:"-",strike:"950.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"4937120138052",name:"",s:"GOOG130531C00955000",e:"OPRA",p:"0.55",cs:"chb",c:"0.00",cp:"0.00",b:"-",a:"0.40",oi:"2",vol:"-",strike:"955.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"217861932232686",name:"",s:"GOOG130531C00960000",e:"OPRA",p:"0.40",cs:"chb",c:"0.00",cp:"0.00",b:"-",a:"0.40",oi:"3",vol:"-",strike:"960.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"},{cid:"312327429834115",name:"",s:"GOOG130531C00965000",e:"OPRA",p:"0.40",cs:"chb",c:"0.00",cp:"0.00",b:"-",a:"0.40",oi:"2",vol:"-",strike:"965.00",expiry:"May 31, 2013"}],underlying_id:"694653",underlying_price:889.58002}
```

Comment: I didn't get any replies on this one. So I'll post a work around which may be helpful to some one having the same problem. It seems JsonSlurper will not parse it, but google's own gson parser has no trouble in parsing the response to a linked TreeMap object. The Gson parser can be downloaded from https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Comment: Well, technically the problem is that there are no quotes around the **keys**. JSON omits the quotes for values when they are numbers, `null`, `true`, or `false`.

Comment: here's what I did with javascript: ```b.body.replace(/(['"])?([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)(['"])?:/g, '"$2": ');```